# Using OWIN to authorize classic ASP pages

Tags: asp-classic, asp.net-identity, httpmodule

I have an ancient Classic ASP website that used to use Windows authentication for access control but this is no longer appropriate. I thought I might try and wrap this website in an ASP.NET MVC 5 app, so I:

- created a new website complete with ASP.NET Identity
- created a user
- copied the Classic ASP website into the root
- viewed the classic ASP website

Now what I need to do is require authorization for all *.asp* pages so that only authorized users can see them. What's the best way of doing this? Maybe I could do something with OWIN?

Crispin

Answer (score 1):

Following [this example](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/307996) I created an HttpModule that came out like this:

```
public class ClassicAspAuthorization : IHttpModule
    {
    private MyEventHandler _eventHandler = null;

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
        context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(OnBeginRequest);
        }

    public delegate void MyEventHandler(Object s, EventArgs e);

    public event MyEventHandler MyEvent
        {
        add { _eventHandler += value; }
        remove { _eventHandler -= value; }
        }

    public void OnBeginRequest(Object s, EventArgs e)
        {
        HttpApplication app = s as HttpApplication;

        if (app.Request.CurrentExecutionFilePathExtension.EndsWith(".asp") == true && blnIsAuthenticated() == false)
            {
            app.Context.Response.Redirect("/Account/Login");
            }

        if (_eventHandler != null)
            {
            _eventHandler(this, null);
            }
        }
```

and the boolean (*blnIsAuthenticated*) method that determined whether or not the user was authenticated was derived from a [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27082598/using-asp-net-identity-2-cookie-in-forms-authentication) where I removed the lines:

```
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, authenticationType, ClaimTypes.Name, ClaimTypes.Role);

var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
```

and replaced this with my own claims checking to establish if the user was authenticated. An appropriate boolean value was returned.