# ASP.Net Identity 2.0 and ASP Classic Interop

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, owin, asp.net-identity-2

I'm trying to get an ASP Classic site running side by side with ASP.Net 5.0. The ASP Classic site has a homebrew authentication mechanism, but if I can get `Request.ServerVariables("AUTH_USER")` set, I can bridge between the two.

I can get things working using `FormsAuthentication`. To do this I write my own ASP.NET 5.0 login controller method that uses `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie` if login is successful. To protect non ASP.Net assets, I reregister the relevant modules without a precondition in `Web.Config`

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
        <add name="FormsAuthenticationModule" type="System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule" />
        ... same for UrlAuthorization and DefaultAuthentication
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

**If I want to move to ASP.Net 5.0 cookie authentication, is there a way to get the relevant OWIN authentication modules to run on all requests in a similar way?**

For what it's worth, I can get this working if I set `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests` to true. This is generally considered a sledgehammer to crack a nut. Is there a way to limit to just the necessary authentication modules?

[Using ASP.Net Identity 2 cookie in forms authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27082598/using-asp-net-identity-2-cookie-in-forms-authentication) looks promising, but it seems odd that you would need to know the format of the Cookie (plus it looks hard coded to version 1).

Comment: The cookies are not interchangeable, so it stands to reason if you have to write your own HTTPHandler to deal with it would need to know the structure of said cookie, it's all there in [that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27092433/692942) and [associated blog article](http://lbadri.wordpress.com/2014/11/23/reading-katana-cookie-authentication-middlewares-cookie-from-formsauthenticationmodule/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using ASP.Net Identity 2 cookie in forms authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27082598/using-asp-net-identity-2-cookie-in-forms-authentication)

Comment: I'm not asking for the cookies to be interchangeable. I want to get rid of the FormsAuthentication cookie and replace it with the ASP.Net Identity stuff. The only problem is getting the authentication handler to run for non-ASP.Net assets.

Comment: and the answer is there, you need to write a custom HTTPHandler.

Comment: Plus I was mainly commenting on *"but it seems odd that you would need to know the format of the Cookie"*. You need to know the format, to be able to build a HTTPHandler to process it.

Comment: It seems odd because surely the framework has code for encoding and decoding these things.

Comment: If it did, then that answer wouldn't have 10 up-votes. So what is your question, why do I need to handle this myself? Simple, .Net doesn't support it out of the box.